# Linear probability model difference in difference?

Tags: regression, econometrics, difference-in-difference, consistency

I see frequently people opposed to linear probability models for binary outcomes, and I know there are related questions to this on this forum, but I want to make sure my understanding is correct. Lets say I have a binary outcome and am primarily interested in the causal effect, so I run a linear probability model instead of logit or other limited dependent variable models

In this case as long as I adjust for heteroscedasticity- isn't the linear probability model consistent? (assume exogenous treatment)- the Conditional expectation of interest is the difference in difference of  expectations (probabilities that y = 1)- so the LPM just give a difference in difference in means, and each mean will converge in probability to the underlying expectation by the law of large numbers and thus there is no need to do something else like a nonlinear model?

Is this understanding correct or am I missing something that critics of the LPM would point out?

Comment: Typically you want to use clustered errors in a DID to allow within panel error correlation, and not just het-robust ones.

Comment: what is causal effect? I have not heard that term before. The strongest criticism of LPM is that they can generate probabilities greater than one, which is obviously impossible (and of course biased since it has to be wrong). I think they are inherently non-linear as well and the assumption of linear regression obviously is that the results are linear.